# Непонятное исключение при работе с Google Docs Api

Tags: c#, .net, google-docs-api

Есть данный снизу кусок кода для получения текста из гугл документа. При запуске кода в строке AuthorizeAsync выскакивает исключение:

> System.InvalidOperationException: "At least one client secrets (Installed or Web) should be set"

В чем может быть ошибка?

```
 UserCredential credential;

        using (var stream = new FileStream("credentials.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            string credPath = "token.json";

            credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                Scopes,
                "user",
                CancellationToken.None,
                new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
            Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);

        }
        var service = new DocsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = applicationName,
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Здесь пример который создает `VisionService` используя обьект `GoogleCredential` созданный с `json` файла с `ServiceAccountCredential`.

```
GoogleCredential credential;
using (var stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    credential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream)
        .CreateScoped(VisionService.Scope.CloudPlatform);
}

var service = new VisionService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
    ApplicationName = "my-app-name",
});
```

Даный код требует двух нюгетов:

```
Google.Apis.Vision.v1  
Google.Apis.Oauth2.v2
```

даный ответ - перевод https://stackoverflow.com/a/37068732/4423545

Comment: Да , спасибо , я видел это решение. Но как помощью VisionService ,например, вывести заголовок документа?

Answer (score 0):

Наконец-то разобрался) Проблема была в самом json файле. В его начале нужно было прописать installed.